# gettext() translates only en_US

Tags: php, windows, xampp, gettext

I've just started using `gettext()` and having a strange problem. I have the following code:

```
// $language = ["en_US", "en_US.UTF-8", "en-US", "en-US.UTF-8"];
// $language = ["tr_TR", "tr-TR", "tr", "tr_TR.UTF-8", "tr-TR.UTF-8", "tr.UTF-8"];
$language = ["nl_NL", "nl_NL.UTF-8", "nl-NL", "nl-NL.UTF-8"];

putenv("LANG=" . $language[0]);
$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "locales"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
textdomain($domain);

if (!defined("LC_MESSAGES")) {
    echo "<p>LC_MESSAGES is NOT defined.</p>";
}

if (!function_exists("gettext")) {
    echo "<p>gettext() does not exist.</p>";
}

echo "<p>" . $locale . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . _("title") . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . _("content") . "</p>";
```

This doesn't work on localhost (XAMPP 7.3.5), or rather it works (translates) only with `en_US`. The output I get is:

```
LC_MESSAGES is NOT defined.

nl_NL

_TITLE_

_CONTENT_
```

While it should translate `en` to `nl`, I get `en -> en`. This works fine on a remote server (DirectAdmin) and I don't get `LC_MESSAGES` error:

```
nl_NL

titel

inhoud
```

This problem might be specific to XAMPP, and I think this is vital. I should be able to use/change languages on localhost. What can be done to solve this? The only difference that I've noticed between the servers is that `LC_MESSAGES` is not defined on localhost (XAMPP). And in [setlocale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) page, there's a statement saying:

> LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)

Could this be the reason? Do I need to recompile PHP?

If there isn't a way to fix this, is there a workaround that I can use? I mean, I already have the required po/mo files. I know the directory that they're in. I know the requested locale. All I need would be a parser to get the translation from the file.

<sub>All files can be found at [this repository](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/tree/master/php/xampp/i18n).</sub>
<sub>Remote server [output](http://185.42.172.162/~lab/i18n/) (page/link might be removed in the future).</sub>

---

**Update**

I'm constantly looking for a way to solve this, so I'm checking other Q/As. In one, it's suggested that I have to install the language that I want to use. So I downloaded/installed the languages (tr, nl). It didn't help. It still doesn't translate.

[image: screenshot of language settings]

Comment: I've checked tens of posts about this problem, and it seems looking further is a waste of time. This problem is mentioned/documented in many places. I'll probably not use gettext :(

Answer (score 0):

Locale identifiers like `nl_NL` are not standardized and your Windows system may use something different.  Try outputting the return value of `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` to get an idea of the format used.

You should also read the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

You will find this:

> On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).

So you should ensure that you have selected Dutch, before you make the test call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)`.

And about the supported locale categories you can find in the docs:

> LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)

So, the constant `LC_MESSAGES` may just not be defined for your version of PHP.

But ... I am not a PHP programmer but your sample code does not look correct. How can a string literal like "LC_MESSAGES" not be defined? Please post the original code.

Comment: That's why instead of just passing `"nl_NL"`, I'm passing an array of identifiers. OS picks whatever is available. Also I've posted a link to the original code (repository). It's in the question. You can just install XAMPP and try the code yourself.